Is the construction "to try and [verb]" now considered standard, as in "to try and explain......"?
This question is about a construction that I find mildly (only mildly) irritating, but  baffling.  See example below. I know what the phrase means when it is used, but why do people use it?  Has it become standard usage?  Is everything that most people understand the meaning of 90% along the way to becoming standard usage?
Why do people say, for example, "He will try and explain quantum mechanics", instead of "He will try to explain quantum mechanics"?
Please try to explain why this usage is so common.

I think I formatted the example text of the query, but it is confusingly self-referencing. I can't see the relevance or the meaning of your second irritation.

@Weather Vane   Only to acknowledge that there are much worse common usages.  Will delete it.

Sorry you don't like the blockquote formatting.

People also write and say "I should of [done something]" instead of "I should have [done something]", because their grammar is not very good.

Quite possibly covered as well as possible at Why do we say try and {verb} instead of try to {verb}, eg try and call?

This usage is an idiomatic use of "and" in pseudo-coordination in relation with certain verbs;it is not particular to "try", although "try" is the prototypical verb in this small set of verbs;  it is informal and can be derogatory. The verb "try" (and a few others) appear to subordinate their lexical meaning to the adjunct, and so, take on a quasi-auxiliary role in the clause (in particular as concerns "try"; for instance, for "try" no finite verb form coordination is possible).  In American English, "and" is sometimes suppressed.

Obligatory predication adjuncts
(CoGEL § 8.30)
[In]

"She'll come to see you (about it)." and
"I went to visit my mother.",

the lexical force of the main verb is reduced and the adjunct ("to see you (about it)", "to visit my mother"), while
having the form common in the semantic role of purpose, is predominantly
concerned with the respect role. This applies even more obviously to the
obligatory adjunct following try:

He must try to do better (next time).
[ ≠ . . . 'so as to do better', 'in order to do better']

These adjuncts are noteworthy in that the semantic relation is alternatively
realized by coordinated clauses, especially in rather informal usage […]:

She'll come and see you (about it).
I went and visited my mother.
He must try and do better (next time).

Note
[a] When the coordinated clause is finite, the sense of the preceding verb is tilted towards its full lexical meaning. Compare:

I'll go and visit my mother.
I went and visited my mother.
I went and I visited my mother.

It is only in the first of these that the coordinated part has the resemblance to obligatory adjunct.
With try, no finite verb coordination is possible:

Did he try and see you?
*Yes, he tried and saw me.

[b] Since go, sit, try, etc with infinitive clauses as obligatory adjunct seem to subordinate their lexical meaning to the verb in the adjunct, it is of interest to compare them with auxiliary verbs.
[…].



(CoGEL § 13.98) Pseudo-coordination : try and come, etc
When they precede and, members of a small class of verbs or predications
have an idiomatic function which is similar to the function of catenative
constructions […] and which will be termed PSEUDO-COORDINATION. The
clearest example is try:

I'll try and come tomorrow.

This is roughly equivalent to I'll try to come tomorrow, but is more informal in style. Further:

They sat and talked about the good old times.

is similar in meaning to  They sat talking about the good old times.   Pseudo-coordination belongs to informal style, and many examples have a derogatory connotation:

Don't just stand there and grin. [= stand there grinning]
He went and complained about us.
They've gone and upset her again.
Run and tell him to come here at once.
Why did you go and do a silly thing like that?

Like try in being followed by a to-infinitive in the corresponding regular form are stop, go, come, hurry up, and run. Like sit are stand and (positional) lie.
This quasi-auxiliary use of try appears to be limited to the base form of the verb. Contrast the acceptability of:

Try and see him tomorrow.
He may try and see us tomorrow.
They try and see us every day.

with the unacceptability of:

*He tried and saw us yesterday.

*She has tried and spoken to him.

*He tries and sees us every day.

Instead of coordination, in such cases, we have to use the to-infinitive; eg:

He tried to see us every day.


 Note
[a] Of the two -ed participle forms of go […] both gone and been occur in pseudo-coordination in BrE, but only gone occurs in pseudo-coordination in AmE:

They've gone and spilled wine on the floor. (BrE and AmE)
They've been and spilled wine on the floor. (BrE)
The normal meaning of go is lost in these sentences. There is no aspectual difference between them, of the kind normally associated with gone and been  […], and both usages are informal and derogatory. BrE has a humorous usage in which both been and gone are conjoined with a third verb: Look what you've been and gone and done.

[b] In familiar speech we also find the idiom:

He up and hit me. He upped and hit me.
and hit me.
She up and left him. She upped and left him.


Practical English Usage (Michael Swan, second edition, 1980)

In informal American English, and is sometimes dropped after the base forms go and come.

Let's go see if Anne's home.
Go jump in the river.
Come sit on my lap.


It seems that this idiomatic usage is more frequent in BrE than AmE; some information I once read  on this point remains vague in my mind but the following two ngrams seem to confirm the reality of a significantly smaller frequency (although growing with time).



Better answer than in previous threads, but estimates of acceptability would perhaps require comparisons of the usage levels of 'try and V' vs 'try to V'. CoGEL is dated and hedges comments on acceptability.

@EdwinAshworth In fact, CGEL says "And can be replaced by
the infinitival marker to, and being slightly more informal than to (although "to" is not at all informal).

Why do people say "try and do something"?
Who knows. I don't know why people ever use bad grammar but it certainly does seem to be very popular to use this construction. I would say, however, that its use is only acceptable in spoken language, or in writing that represents spoken language.
I would not use "try and do something" in a formal context, eg a work document, where it should be "try to do something".

It has been argued that this is hendiadys, a recognised if rare figure of speech, rather than bad grammar. But an answer about acceptability needs to be substantiated by references or appropriate data; answers lacking such tend to come over as (and may indeed be) merely personal opinion.
